# How to retrieve information from curl using python subprocess

Tags: python, curl

I'm using curl.exe on windows. But unfortunately I can't get back data from console.

python code looks like this:

```
tid = subprocess.Popen("C:/users/zero/Desktop/lm/curl.exe -i -H \"Cookie: login=" + userhash + "\" -F \"type=" + caid + "\" -F \"description=\" -F \"descr=" + cleaned + "\" -F \"filetype=2\" -F \"name=" + pavadinimas + "\" -F \"file=@" + namel + "\" -F \"tag=@" + nto + "\" http://www.isos.lt/upload.php")
```

I tried with process.returncode to retrieve the information, but I don't get correct info.
I can see that info in cmd but I don't know how to get it. Maybe it's possible to get that info with stdout=subprocess.PIPE, process.communicate()?

EDIT:

This command posted by sukhbir  helped. Thanks.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

Where command is your command.
```

Comment: "EDIT: SOLVED" is rude.  Please post the actual answer.  You are allowed to answer your own question so that others may learn.  "EDIT: SOLVED" helps no one.

Answer (score 7):

Using curl via subprocess is the hard way. Spare yourself the trouble and use [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) or [pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/).

[update]

Currently, the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library is the best option for this kind of thing.

Comment: +1 for requests. I could not believe the insanity of setup required by urllib and pycurl. The requests site is right: it shouldn't be this way in Python.

Answer (score 1):

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Where `command` is your command.

Comment: And yes, listen to Paulo's advice.

Comment: It's good that it works, but there are better alternatives available which will make it easy for you to handle all this. Check out the links as shown by Paulo.